# Can't figure out best way to display joined data in Rails 5 with has_many_through relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through, join

I have 3 models: Cinema, Movie and Run. Cinema and Movie has a relationship through Run, like so:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cinemas, -> { distinct }, through: :runs
  has_many :runs
end
```

I'm trying to display list of cinemas of certain movie with list of runs for each cinema:

**Movie 1**

1. Cinema 1

   - 12:30
   - 15:00
2. Cinema 2

   - 15:30
   - 16:00

I can't figure out how to reduce database calls. Right now i'm making a call for each cinema, so its proportional for number or cinemas. Doesn't seems right to me

```
@movie.cinemas.each do |cinema|
   cinema.runs.where(movie_id: @movie.id).each do |run|
      = run.time
```

Need help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add relationship to `Run` first

```
class Run < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :cinema
end
```

Then use `includes` and start the loop from `runs`.

For example:

```
@movie = Movie.where(... the condition ...).includes(:runs => :cinemas).first
@movie.runs.group_by(&:cinema_id).each do |movie_id, runs|
  <%= runs.first.cinema.name %>
  runs.each do |run|
    <%= run.time %>
  end
end
```

---

Note that

```
runs.group_by(&:cinema_id)
```

is a syntax sugar of

```
runs.group_by{|run| run.cinema_id }
```

The usage example of [group_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) method:

```
(1..6).group_by {|i| i%3}   #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
```

Comment: But what about list of cinemas?

Comment: you could use `runs.first.cinema`

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it as `runs.first.movie`

Comment: Thanks, but it works only if i change **@movie.runs.group_by(&:movie_id)** to **@movie.runs.group_by(&:cinema_id)**

Can you explain what "&" in "(&:cinema_id)" means?